# Binding a managed bean instance to composite component

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component, managed-bean

I have a composite component (collapsiblePanel). The component uses the "collapsible" bean to provide the toggle function. When I use the same component multiple times on a page, each instance of the component is bound to the same bean instance. How Can I achieve something like a component scoped bean?

`collapsibleTemp.xhtml`:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="model" required="true">
        <cc:attribute name="collapsed" required="true" />
        <cc:attribute name="toggle" required="true"
            method-signature="java.lang.String f()" />
    </cc:attribute>
    <cc:actionSource name="toggle" />
    <cc:facet name="header" />
    <cc:facet name="body" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="collapsiblePanel-header">
        <h:commandButton id="toggle" action="#{cc.attrs.model.toggle}"
            styleClass="collapsiblePanel-img"
            image="#{cc.attrs.model.collapsed ? '/resources/images/plus.png' : '/resources/images/minus.png'}" />
        <cc:renderFacet name="header" />
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{!cc.attrs.model.collapsed}">
        <cc:insertChildren />
        <cc:renderFacet name="body"></cc:renderFacet>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="components.css" />
</cc:implementation>
```

The backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Collapsible {

    private boolean collapsed = false;

    public boolean isCollapsed() {
        return collapsed;
    }

    public void setCollapsed(boolean collapsed) {
        this.collapsed = collapsed;
    }

    public String toggle() {
        collapsed = !collapsed;
        return null;
    }

}
```

Using Page

```
<h:form id="someid">
    <jl:collapsibletemp id="collapsiblePanel1" model="#{collapsible}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h3>
                <h:outputText value="Collapsible information" />
            </h3>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="body">
            <h:outputText value="do something....." />
        </f:facet>
        <p />
    </jl:collapsibletemp>

    <jl:collapsibletemp id="collapsiblePanel2" model="#{collapsible}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h3>
                <h:outputText value="Collapsible information" />
            </h3>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="body">
            <h:outputText value="do some tabbing" />
        </f:facet>
        <p />
    </jl:collapsibletemp>

    <jl:collapsibletemp id="collapsiblePanel3" model="#{collapsible}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h3>
                <h:outputText value="Collapsible information" />
            </h3>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="body">
            <h:outputText value="notice board" />
        </f:facet>
        <p />
    </jl:collapsibletemp>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `componentType` attribute of the `<cc:interface>` to define a "backing component".

E.g.

```
<cc:interface componentType="collapsiblePanel">
    ...
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    ...
    <h:commandButton action="#{cc.toggle}" ... />
    ...
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!cc.collapsed}" ...>
    ...
</cc:implementation>
```

with just a `com.example.components.CollapsiblePanel`

```
@FacesComponent(value="collapsiblePanel") // To be specified in componentType attribute.
public class CollapsiblePanel extends UINamingContainer { // Important! Must extend UINamingContainer.

    private boolean collapsed;

    public void toggle() {
        collapsed = !collapsed;
    }

    public boolean isCollapsed() {
        collapsed;
    }

}
```

**However**, when you want to have multiple of those components, then you should declare *physically separate* instances of them in the view. If this needs to happen dynamically, then you need to use `<c:forEach>` to generate physically separate instances of them instead of `<ui:repeat>` with a single component. Otherwise you have to map all `collapsed` states by the client ID inside a `Map<String, Boolean>`. See for an example and more background information also [Getting same instance of `componentType` in composite component on every use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485062/getting-same-instance-of-componenttype-in-composite-component-on-every-use)

Comment: This solution works partially. When I toggle one component, the other component also gets toggled.
I have manually declared the components 3 times. When I toggle on any one component, the other 2 also toggle.

<jl:collapsibletemp id="collapsiblePanel1"></jl:collapsibletemp>

<jl:collapsibletemp id="collapsiblePanel2"></jl:collapsibletemp>

<jl:collapsibletemp id="collapsiblePanel3"></jl:collapsibletemp>

Thanks for your help. Please let me know what I could do to make these components completely independent of each other.

Comment: This is exactly what I already predicted and covered in the last paragraph of my answer. Use `<c:forEach>` or hold the booleans in a map with client ID as key.

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested. But still it does not seem to work. 
Using Page: 
<js:forEach items="#{widgets.windows}" var="window"> <jl:collapsibletemp id="collapsiblePanel#{window.name}" /> </js:forEach> 

@ManagedBean(name="widgets") public class Widgets { public List<Window> getWindows() { if(windows == null){ windows = new ArrayList<Window>(); windows.add(new Window("one", "one header", "one body")); windows.add(new Window("two", "two header", "two body")); }  return windows;

Even after adding the collapsed states into a map, they do not behave like independent components.

Comment: `@FacesComponent(value = "collPanelTwo")  
class CollPanel extends UICompBase implements NContainer {  
 public void toggle(ActionEvent evt) {  
  collapsed = !collapsed;  
  testMap.put(getClientId(), isCollapsed());  
 }  
 public boolean isCollapsed() {  
  return testMap.get(getClientId());  
 }`

USING PAGE  
<jl:collapsibleComponent clientId="one">facets...
<jl:collapsibleComponent clientId="two">facets... 

I have manually added 2 components in the views. They do not behave like independent components. I also tried <jstl:forEach but it never rendered as an independent component

Comment: Thanks BalucS. I had to work around a bit to get it to work. I used the stateHelper to preserve the state.